# Will this setup cause a Bottleneck Connection / Speed issues?

Tags: networking, router, switch, cat6, cat5

I'll have one cat6 cable running from my **router to a switch**. That switch will then give internet and network access to **5+ devices**.

Will this cause a bottleneck / anything negative if all devices are used at the same time, being that the switch is only running from one ethernet connection?
I'm not that tech savvy so this may be a stupid question.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the limited info you have given us, the answer will depends on your internet connection. Unless you have fiber optic , You should be fine.

I can give you a more detailed answer if you give me the link speeds for each of your devices and the approx speed of your router connection.

Comment: I'm on a 30mbps DL and a 2 Upload (Fiber). How do I go about getting link speeds for each device? Any other info you need? Thank you!

Comment: It depends on what you want to use your network for. It is it just browsing the internet or are you going to use the network for more intensive purpose ?

Comment: Mainly browsing the net, serving files and media. Nothing too intensive.

Comment: Your setup should be fine. If you have the model numbers/names for your router and switch, you can look up their max link speeds.
For max performance, you would want gigbit connections from your server/s and your client/s system via your switch